What is the reason for Barbie expressing the same sentiment in two different ways?
Barbie speaks to the ghost of Ruth, who is the creator of Barbie:

Barbie: I want to be a part of the people that make meaning.
Not the thing that's made. I want to do the imagining.
I don't wanna be the idea.

All sentences mean: Barbie is expressing her desire to be the one
who imagines or creates, rather than being the subject or
the idea that others create or imagine.
What is the reason for Barbie expressing the same sentiment in two different ways?

Repetition seems to have been used by the writers for emphasis of something important to the character or plot, it's very common. You'll see it a lot. What sort of answer are you looking for?

Repetition is a way of hammering home simple ideas to the audience. It's a way of ensuring they understand the message you're trying to get across.

What is the reason for you posing the question in the title of your post, but then using not exactly the same words in the ultimate sentence in your question?

I don't think that she is saying the same thing four times, but she is making two statements that are similar, which use parallelism to emphasize the content.  She wants to make and imagine things, not being something which is made or imagined. Making and imagining things are not quite the same thing, and it is possible to be both a maker and the made, the dreamer and the dream, so it makes sense that she'd make that distinction.

She is stressed by becoming a human, being chased and meeting her creator for the first time.
Of course she is repeating herself; she’s clearly stressed and nervous.
Barbie is becoming a sentient human being as the film progresses. She feels the feels, but she has trouble expressing herself. Especially in this scene where she is running away from the Mattel executives and stumbles upon her literal creator. This means:

She is becoming more human.
She is being chased.
And then finally, she meets her creator for the literal first time.

All of these are stress including situations. Thus her desire to blurt things out in such a frazzled state results in repetition.
